# Google Adwords API problems with user Authentication

Tags: ruby, google-ads-api

I'm adding campaigns to the particular accounts, so i have an array of accounts, then I get them from db and add campaigns to these accounts.

I connect to the production environment, get the response

```
CONNECTION ESTABLISHED
```

But after when I try to add a campaign i get the error

```
AuthenticationError.NOT_ADS_USER @ ; trigger:'652428713780' Service[CampaignService.mutate]
```

part of the code which invokes this:

```
 @srv[:campaign]= @adwords.get_service('Campaign',AdWords::Service.latest_version)
 def add_campaign(name, cc = 'HU', status = nil, budget = nil)
  budget ||= AdWordsConfig.get('hu_campaign_budget').value.to_f
  status ||= @srv[:campaign].module::CampaignStatus::PAUSED

  operation = {
    :operand => {
    :name                        => "API - #{name}",
    :status                      => status,
      :biddingStrategy             => @srv[:campaign].module::ManualCPC.new,
      :budget => {
      :period                    => 'DAILY',
      :amount => {
      :microAmount             => (budget * AMOUNT_MULTIPLIER)
    },
      :deliveryMethod            => 'ACCELERATED'
    }
  },
    :operator                      => 'ADD'
  }

  response = @srv[:campaign].mutate([operation])
  response.rval.value.first
  cid = response.rval.value.first.id

  response.rval.value.first
end
```

I found out in the google API documentation this error means

```
#   NOT_ADS_USER

  User in the cookie is not a valid Ads user.
```

but i don't even know how to check cookie.
I'm running rake task, is it possible to retrieve cookie after connecting to adwords google com?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to follow the discussion here: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/adwords-api/BT8mM1vaSVE/discussion